# Issue with creating notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have two notification functions that I wrote. They both are working - it's just that the older version uses deprecated methods.  The problem is my new one does not show up across the menu bar and doesn't vibrate or make a noise when it appears.  What do I need to add to it?

Old version:

```
public void createNotification(String message) {    
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);    
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);     
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);     
    Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.logo_small, message,    
            System.currentTimeMillis());    

    n.setLatestEventInfo(this, message, message, pi);    
    n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;     
    nm.notify(12327942 + notidchange, n);     
    ++notidchange;
}
```

New version:

```
public void createNotification(String message) {
    //add diff icons and titles later
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(message)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_small)
            .setAutoCancel(true) //do I want?
            .setContentIntent(pi);
    nm.notify(12327942 + notidchange++, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: add your menifest.xml file here

Answer (score 0):

before nm.notify, put this code

```
Notification notif = builder.build();
notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
notif.ledOnMS = 100; 
notif.ledOffMS = 100;
notif.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
```

and replace `nm.notify(12327942 + notidchange++, builder.build());`
with `nm.notify(12327942 + notidchange++, notif);`